# Problem with back button following a postback on Jquery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm having problems with JQM beta1 (the same thing happens with beta2) and ASP.NET MVC 3.
I have several pages with forms, and they post to the same address of the page, then with MVC  `RedirectToAction` the next page is called.
Initially I had problems with the back button, which I solved by adding the attribute `data-url` to the page div.

But now I have this page that has a server-side validation, so posting back a page with the same `data-url`, when the server-side validation keeps the user on the same page, and then user hits the back button, the url on the browser is changed correctly but the page is not rendered again, it seems to remain the same, then if I hit the back button again I can see the correct page (2 steps behind page).

This should not be so problematic, since there should be many sites using forms with validation and needing the back button working properly.
Is there any special attribute that needs to be set on the page div when the post stays on the same page?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use RemoteAttribute for remote validation